# Current query is not displaying user's full name

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to display user's full name on the page. Should be formatted as follows:

```
Last Suffix, First Middle
```

Below is the query that displays the record on the page.

```
public String getSubjectSql()
{
    return
        " SELECT " +
        " u.c_last_name, u.c_suffix || ', ' || u.c_first_name, u.c_middle_name AS userName, " +
        " FROM t_user u ";
}
```

Right now, it only displays user's middle name on the page. I have a record with the following full name "**Sam Andrew Williams**". I am only seeing "**Andrew**" being outputted.

If I were to display this record in correct format, it should be as following:

```
Williams VII, Sam Andrew
```

Comment: You're using `||` to concatenate strings, except where you're using `,`...  Use `a || b || c || d`

Comment: The comma (,) after userName is probably not supposed to be there though? Should not be using it in the first place anywhere if you're only trying to select a single value concatenated from multiple values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the code you want is:

```
SELECT (u.c_last_name || u.c_suffix || ', ' || u.c_first_name || ' ' || u.c_middle_name) AS userName
FROM t_user u ;
```

You have commas in your expression between the components, rather than `||`.  Hence, your query is returning three columns and only the last gets the alias `userName` (that is why you are getting the middle name).

Note that my habit is to enclose expressions in parentheses.  If you had done this, you would have gotten a syntax error because of the comma.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you @ Gordon Linoff!